# Visual Studio 2017 (and 2015) Hangs on Registration

Tags: visual-studio, installation, registration

I'm running into issues trying to register Visual Studio 2017 and 2015 with my Visual Studio Online Subscription (a.k.a. MSDN). I'm using a VMWare VDI using their Horizon Client if that matters. The OS is Windows 10, and the Visual Studio SKU is Professional. My client requires me to run under two separate identities, one with limited privileges for non-development work, and an administrator account for development work (annoying, but not unreasonable given my client is a very large corporation). So, I run Visual Studio under that admin account using `Run as administrator`.

**My problem**: On the virtual machine Visual Studio hangs when I click the `Sign-In` button, or the `Check for an updated license` on the product registration sign-in page. **Note**: This problem only occurs from the virtual machine using my administrator account. It works fine on the virtual machine under my normal non-admin account. Nor do I have issues on the physical machine I'm using to run the VM. That said, my client requires me to use the virtual machine.

I'm just wondering if anyone else as seen this same issue. There is something about running under my admin account on VMWare that is hanging Visual Studio registration as soon as I click `sign-in`. Likely a firewall or proxy setting, not sure. I'm working closely with my client's IT Operations, but they are as perplexed as I.

Comment: Hi KyleLib, have you tried to create a new administrator account in VM and check if this issue persists or not? If it happens, please close all VS instances, run the command: devenv /log https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 to logs all activity for troubleshooting, upload the ActivityLog.xml file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share link. You can also check this: http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/2016/10/31/howto-diagnose-a-visual-studio-startup-hang-problem/ to find the detail error message.

Comment: Hi Sara - MSFT, yes, another user is experiencing the same issue. As I stated, if I run Visual Studio under my non-admin account registration succeeds. The issue is when I start Visual Studio with "Run as administrator" and enter a different account than the account I am logged in with. I will post the ActivityLog on Monday, however it doesn't really point to any issue. The OnlineLicensing log does show some exceptions however.

Comment: "The issue is when I start Visual Studio with "Run as administrator" and enter a different account than the account I am logged in with.". Do you mean that you use different account to log-in VS? If so, do you install VS as the admin in your side? Do you mean that you could sign-in using previous account? How about sign out it without admin firstly? And then sign in again with the admin using the same account.

Comment: Hi Jach Zhai-MSFT - Yes, I installed Visual Studio using the admin account. while logged into Windows as my normal domain account. My normal account does not have rights to install software, so Windows 10 prompts me to enter an administrator account. I have tried everything you suggested, thus the reason I am posting my question on StackOverflow. I have some ServiceHub logs that may provide some insite into the issue.

Comment: @KyleLib, If possible, you could share the log here. I will view it in my side. But like your previous discussions, since other member also gets the same issue as yours, I suggest you report this feedback here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html?sort=newest. Sorry for that I couldn't repro it using the same Environment as yours, but one possible reason I know is that whether your windows account has the conflicts with your VM log-in account. Anyway, I suggest you report this issue to the developer community site.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT: I have posted an issue on the community site as you suggested. You can find it at developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/119797/…‌​. I had to add the attachments there as a comment, as the Visual Studio "Report a Problem" interface would not allow me to attach files. Thanks

Comment: @KyleLib, Thanks for your share: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/119797/visual-studio-2017-and-2015-hangs-on-registration.html, the report team would provide useful information later, I will also pay attentions to this report.